# SSH from client VM to a server VM - Permission denied

Tags: ssh, virtualbox-networking

After installing two VMs in VirtualBox, I tried to connect them, using ssh protocol from the client machine (with openssh-client installed) to the ssh server machine (with openssh-server installed). Both of machines are in a Host Only Network (named: vboxnet0). When I try, from the client (named: sshclient), to open a ssh connection on the server (named: sshserver and with IP address:192.168.56.3), I get the message: Permission denied, please try again. I typed:`ssh sshclient@sshserver -p 22` and typed the password (correctly, I am sure) 3 times. The port 22 was enabled on the server configuration file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, the PasswordAuthentication line was uncommented and the IP address of the client was added in the file `/etc/hosts`on server side.

What is happened? Any tips to solve?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the client is unable to even attempt to connect to the server try `netstat -tln` on the server. It sounds like it doesn't have port 22 open for some reason.

If :22 isn't listed then try restarting the ssh service.

Also when attempting to connect to a server via ssh the user portion (before the '@' needs to be a user that is on the server. It sounds like you are trying to use the user from the sshClient to login to the sshServer, when in reality this doesn't make sense.

For example:
Let us say that The sshServer has a user ExtraUser and the sshClient has a user Karen. If Karen wants to ssh into the server she will need to type `ssh ExtraUser@sshServer`. This will have her login to the sshServer as ExtraUser, not as Karen. This is important because Karen's user account/permissions is located on the sshClient not the sshServer.

Comment: 1) The output of that command is here: [link]https://pastebin.com/t3EUsMYn 2) So, you mean that the correct typing is: `ssh -v sshserver@sshserver` in my case?

Comment: I think that I should let the server know the user on my client machine before. How to do that?

Comment: Checking better the output of `netstat -tln`, port :22 is about a tcp connection 6,  tcp over ip version 6. Could be this the problem?

Comment: @michele_ub The output of your netstat looks good to me. After the `ssh` part of the command the next part is the username of an existing user on the sshServer. So `ssh user-on-sshServer@sshserver` should work. Though to be safe it would be best to use the ip address of the sshServer instead `sshserver`. Something like `ssh user-on-sshServer@192.168.1.10` or whatever the ip of that machine is on your virtual network.

Comment: How to add a user on the server side or verify the list of user on the server machine so that I can be sure to type the correct user? I have also tried to change the network configuration on my two VMs, using a network NAT instead of a Host Only config. but I get always the same message.

Comment: How do you normally login to your machine? Whatever username you type there try that user and password.

Comment: @michele_ub You just need to use the same user to login to the sshServer as you would normally. Once you do that it should work. Please mark this question as answered

Comment: You were right! I have tried to connect always in the wrong way. Just using `ssh sshserver@ip_address_of_server_side` everything works! I was stupid.